# Передать файл по wifi в приложении с андроида на андроид

Tags: android, wifi, share

Я создаю приложение для передачи файлов через wifi (точка доступа), но я не знаю как программно создать точку доступа и как потом организовать передачу файла, я только знаю как через bluetooth передавать. Хотя-бы как мне просто точку создать?

Comment: Возможно, вам поможет [wifi direct](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct). [Обзор](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html)

Comment: Это работает без промежуточной точки доступа

Comment: Ну незнаю, я посмотрел а там как-то сложно. А как хотя-бы просто точку создать?

Comment: [startLocalOnlyHotspot](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#startLocalOnlyHotspot(android.net.wifi.WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback,%20android.os.Handler)) - локальная точка без доступа к интернету

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984345/how-to-turn-on-off-wifi-hotspot-programmatically-in-android-8-0-oreo тут с примером кода. правда на 10м уже может и не работает. Если на телефоне есть NFC посмотрите примеры c android beam, там есть автонастройка подключения Wifi Direct для передачи файлов.